# Java super() constructor not working?

Tags: java, constructor, super, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a super constructor but I'm still getting the error: Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.
also it seems that in the main class there are 2 constructors? but I don't think that is what causing the error.

Main class:

```
public Block(Material blockMaterialIn, MapColor blockMapColorIn)
{
    this.enableStats = true;
    this.blockSoundType = SoundType.STONE;
    this.blockParticleGravity = 1.0F;
    this.slipperiness = 0.6F;
    this.blockMaterial = blockMaterialIn;
    this.blockMapColor = blockMapColorIn;
    this.blockState = this.createBlockState();
    this.setDefaultState(this.blockState.getBaseState());
    this.fullBlock = this.getDefaultState().isOpaqueCube();
    this.lightOpacity = this.fullBlock ? 255 : 0;
    this.translucent = !blockMaterialIn.blocksLight();
}

public Block(Material materialIn)
{
    this(materialIn, materialIn.getMaterialMapColor());
}
```

sub class:

```
public class ItemVoidiom_Ore extends Block {

public ItemVoidiom_Ore(Material materialIn) {
    super(materialIn);
}

public ItemVoidiom_Ore()  /** the error is here, Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor. */
{   setUnlocalizedName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getUnlocalizedName());
    setRegistryName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getRegistryName());
}
```

}
Thanks for any help!

Edit: i've defined the object here, in a different class

```
public static Block voidiom_ore;

public static void init()
{
    voidiom_ore = new ItemVoidiom_Ore();
}
```

Edit: fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: `ItemVoidiom_Ore()` tries to invoke `Block()` which doesn't exist. You must specify which super class constructor to execute explicitly.

Comment: `ItemVoidiom_Ore()` implicitly starts with `super()`, which means it is trying to use a constructor matching `Block()`.

Comment: I dont quite understand Eran..

Comment: The problem is that the compiler only adds a default constructor (without params) when you don't define another one. In your Block class you have defined 2 constructors both with params, so you must use one of this since Block() is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that there is no constructor `Block()`. Either define a constructor `Block()` with no-args or explicitly call `Block(Material blockMaterialIn, MapColor blockMapColorIn)` or `Block(Material materialIn)` from `ItemVoidiom_Ore()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second constructor `public ItemVoidiom_Ore()` is not invoking any of the superclass's constructors.

You need to explicitly call one of the two superclass constructors (as you did in the first one).

Answer (score 0):

**A default constructor is a constructor without parameters.**

---

When no explicit call is done to `super` (the constructor of super class) a call to the default constructor of super class is done.

In your second constructor you have no explicit call to super constructor, you need to change the code to something explicitly calling the constructor of super class:

```
public ItemVoidiom_Ore() { 
    // Here you need to call super(Material blockMaterialIn, MapColor blockMapColorIn);
    // or super(Material materialIn)
    setUnlocalizedName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getUnlocalizedName());
    setRegistryName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getRegistryName());
}
```

You need to call explicitly the one of existing constructors of the super class.

---

Another alternative is to add a default constructor to the super class Block.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, each constructor MUST invoke some constructor of the super class, all the way up to `java.lang.Object`. If you don't add a `super(...)` invocation yourself, this will be added for you automatically at the beginning of your constructor.

In your case the `ItemVoidiom_Ore` constructor does not contain any `super(...)`, so the code behaves as if you wrote `super()` at the beginning. However, the class `Block` does not contain a constructor without arguments.

To solve the issue, you can add a default constructor to `Block`, or add a `super(...)` call providing arguments for one of the two constructor variants in `Block`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public ItemVoidiom_Ore() {   setUnlocalizedName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getUnlocalizedName());
    setRegistryName(Reference.enumstuff.VOIDIOM_ORE.getRegistryName());
}
```

Since you didn't mention which constructor of `Block` (the super) to use Java tries to use the default constructor but it doesn't exist so Java doesn't know which constructor to use to build `Block`. Either add a default constructor to `Block` or call to one of its 2 constructors

Answer (score 0):

A class constructor must always, as its first action, call one of its superclass' constructors.

For your first `ItemVoidiom_Ore` constructor, this is done explicitly:

```
public ItemVoidiom_Ore(Material materialIn) {
    super(materialIn); // calls Block(Material) constructor
}
```

For your other `ItemVoidiom_Ore` constructor, it is not done explicitly, so there is an implicit call to the (non-existent) default constructor of Block.

You either need to add an explicit call to an existing `Block` constructor (as in the other `ItemVoidiom_Ore` constructor), or add an appropriate default (no parameters) constructor to `Block`.

Answer (score 0):

Please define no-argument constructor for Block.

public Block(){}